# Logstash priorities for different logs

Tags: logstash

Is there a way to set up priorities for different types of logs in logstash? 
For example, set the highest priority to critical system logs.

Comment: Do you want to give them priority in ingesting or just add a field to specific log files that says what their priority is for searching in some other tool (ie kibana)?

Comment: The first. For example, if LS (logstash) will have 2 logs - one with high priority and another not, it will firstly send with high priority.

Comment: As far as I've seen, no. Logstash uses FIFO queues internally, so events will always be processed in the order they're received. You could potentially write your own input/output plugins for LS -- it's not as hard as it sounds. Among other things, you might be able to insert a Redis broker that sorts messages internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two queues, I'm doing this in my setup.

I use rabbitmq as queue to send logs

I have two queues:

- logs.info
- logs.critical

Then set workers to consume from one of each queue.

If you have 1M logs in queue logs.info, and none in logs.critical, if you receive a new critical log it will be processed right away.